# How to match search terms within quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search

I am trying to parse a search term. The search term is one long string such as:

```
label:none author:@root label:~"To+Do" label:~'"test me"' label:~"No Label" label:~'won"t fix' this is a search term
```

I am trying to parse it into individual key value pairs:

```
[{label: "none"}, {author:"@root"}, {label:"~\"To+Do\""}, {label: "~"test me\""}, {label: "~\"No Label\""}, {label: "~won\"t fix"}, {search: "this is a search term"}]
```

The search term is the last item without a key. If the search terms have spaces they are wrapped in quoted.

I started to parse this by doing:

```
(label:.*?|author:.*?|milestone:.*?)
```

I am not sure if that will work, but I am also kind of confused on how to get the last search term. Not even sure if this is possible.

The biggest problem is that things are quoted and I am not sure how to match things that are quoted. In the end what I am trying to do is split a string by spaces while ignoring the quotes surrounding spaces.

I use `@` for author, `~` for label, `%` for milestone.

Comment: I don't understand what's your actual need: sure we can easily "transcribe" from 1st to 2nd structure you show, but what's the matter about _search_ here?

Comment: @cFreed I updated the question.

Comment: your one long string is not a string, with ' ' and " "

Comment: @Mr.Bruno You'd have to escape it properly. or use ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work... I also converted the output struct to something easier to work with:

```js
term = `label:none author:@root label:~"To+Do" label:~'"test me"' label:~"No Label" label:~'won"t fix' this is a search term`

re = /(\w+):([~%@]?)(?:"(.*?)"|'(.*?)'|(\S+))/g;

opts = [];

term = term.replace(re, function (_, prop, operator, v1, v2, v3) {
    opts.push({prop, operator, value: v1 || v2 || v3});
    return '';
});

opts.push({search: term.trim()});

console.log(opts);
```

Comment: that is quite impressive. I updated the question with some of the other grammar symbols I use.